# Equation numbering with previews in Rmarkdown to pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown

In Rmarkdown, knitting to PDF, if I write an equation like

```
\begin{equation}
y = x^2
\end{equation}
```

then I get a numbered equation in the PDF output.

If I write an equation like

```
$$ y=x^3 $$
```

Then the equation isn't numbered. I like being able to control which equations are numbered and which aren't, so having two ways to do it, one of which produces numbering, is good. But, the equations that I write with `\begin{}....\end{}` don't get a rendered preview in the editor in Rstudio, while the equations written with `$$...$$` do get rendered. Is there some way to get the numbering without losing the previewing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandoc automatically changes your `$$` delimiters to LaTeX-style `\[` and `\]`, so if you redefine those, you can get numbered equations.  For example:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

\renewcommand{\[}{\begin{equation}}
\renewcommand{\]}{\end{equation}}

This equation is numbered:

$$
x = y^2
$$

This one isn't:

$$
x = y^3 \nonumber
$$
```

If you are using some template that doesn't do the conversion to `\[` and `\]` you can enter those yourself, but RStudio does previewing differently with those, just showing popups, not a static preview.

**Edited to add:**  If you want the default to remain unnumbered, I don't think there's an inverse to `\nonumber` already defined.  You could probably work out a LaTeX macro to do it, or if there are only a few numbered equations, just do them manually using `\tag{number}`, e.g.

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

This equation is fixed as equation (2):

$$
x = y^2 \tag{2}
$$

This one isn't:

$$
x = y^3
$$
```

Maybe someone else will let you know how to do auto-numbering as well.

Comment: This is super. Any way to get the inverse? (i.e. default state is no numbering, add some flag to number a particular equation).

Comment: I've added a partial answer.

Comment: Aha I did not know that \tag{} would work there...thanks again

Comment: This answer is so underrated. Thank you for restoring me back to sanity!