# Equation numbering in R package vignette?

Tags: r, r-markdown, equation, r-package, vignette

What is the idiomatic way to include dynamically numbered equations in the vignette for an R package? I see that there are [options with pandoc-crossref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999522/8400969) and [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html#cross-ref). I created my vignette using `usethis::use_vignette()` and trying to find a combination of yaml header and equation-writing that works. Is there a way to add dynamically updated numbers to equations written like $$y = mx+b$$ ?

I'd love an answer that includes the YAML header and an example equation. So far I have

```
---
title: "using_mypackage"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{using_mypackage}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
something about my first equation

$$y = mx+b \tag{1}$$
```

I also see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61738958/8400969) option works great when the output is set to `pdf_document` instead of `html_vignette`; if there's a way to make that work across output types that would be perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe package [mathjaxr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mathjaxr) can be of help, it allows for [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) in R documentation.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I'd love to avoid additional dependencies in this package, do I need mathjax? It seems like the .rmd parsing of latex equations is adequate for a vignette for the most part, especially if I can solve this piece. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/323